# Are Legendary Weapons levelled off the player's level or the enemy's level in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

When a Legendary enemy is defeated in Fallout 4 they "drop" a Legendary item. These items are randomly generated but the "level" of items (ie. usefulness, value) appear to increase as the player progresses through the game.

Travelling East or South early in the game exposes the player to higher level enemies so it is possible to engage with enemies many levels above the player.

If a level 10 player defeats a level 30 Legendary enemy would they get the same "level" Legendary item (ie. usefulness, value) as a level 30 player defeating a level 30 enemy?

Comment: Weapons have levels?

Comment: Certain items will not appear until your character is at a certain level, guns and power armor types specifically are some.

Comment: @Dupree3 - that seems to apply for looting containers etc. but you can still take "higher level" items off fallen enemies. For example I picked up a Assault Rifle at under level 10 by killing a higher level (Skulled) enemy.

Comment: I don't know about legendary items specifically, but when I kill someone of higher level they have better loot than someone of lower level, so it looks to me like the loot is based on the monster level.

Comment: I doubt it. I think it's luck of the draw - and probably character luck. I'm on lv 70 and murdering some tough fools in far harbor. I still get useless things like pipes, pool cues, boards. Unless you're just bored and want to see how good you are with a blunt object, these things are useless and hard to imagine they were distributed according to your level or the levels of the monsters you would be facing by the time you're ready to take on far harbor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in Fallout 4 don't have levels, not in the way many players are used to anyway. An unmodified Pipe Pistol has the same "level" as a fully modified Combat Rifle. But we can all agree that the Combat Rifle is most likely alot better than the Pipe Pistol. That said, the level of mobs does correspond to the quality of items they carry. You will not see lower level mobs drop Combat Rifles or Combat Armor.

To answer your question: there is no rank or level among legendary item effects. You are as likely to get a "Crippling" as you are a "Wounding" effect on your loot, no matter the level of the mob. However, the modding system of Fallout 4 allows you to modify your weapon very freely.

Comment: So in effect if I use a low level character on high level legendary enemies I'll get a higher "level" (more effective/ damage/ protection/ value) item with a randomly chosen Legendary effect. So the effectiveness/ value is related to the enemy level rather than the player.